# Reusing a segment control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have made a segment control like so...

1. I have dragged a segment control into my view controller in storyboard and made it 5 segments.

2.I made a class called `Enums.swift` like so...

```
import UIKit

enum HomeOptions: String, RawRepresentable {
  case ViewAll, News, Articles, Post, Offers

  var title: String {
    switch self {
    case .ViewAll:
      return "View All"
    case .News:
      return "News"
    case .Articles:
      return "Articles"
    case .Post:
      return "Post"
    case .Offers:
      return "Offers"
    }
  }

}
```

3.In the `viewDidLoad` of viewController, I added these lines..

```
    homeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    homeSegment.setTitle(HomeOptions.ViewAll.title, forSegmentAt: 0)
    homeSegment.setTitle(HomeOptions.News.title, forSegmentAt: 1)
    homeSegment.setTitle(HomeOptions.Articles.title, forSegmentAt: 2)
    homeSegment.setTitle(HomeOptions.Post.title, forSegmentAt: 3)
    homeSegment.setTitle(HomeOptions.Offers.title, forSegmentAt: 4)
```

Now these lines of code sets the appropriate names in the respective segments.

But my concern is this..

If I am required to add another segment control elsewhere in the app with say 3 segments and different segment options, then I don't want to drag another segment-control in that view and repeat the above code/procedure again. But instead I want to add/drag the segment control once only somewhere in the app and also include the other options (of segment control) in the Enums and use them as and when necessary. Can I achieve that..?

Comment: then you will have to create it programatically

Comment: Ok...Any suggestions as to how, @Shahzaib Qureshi..?

Comment: you can send home options in an array and return the view. loop over the array of type HomeOptions and add them all.

Comment: ok..But that is for the options right..?how do I reuse the segment control..? @Naresh

Comment: for that you can use a singleton

Comment: are you sure you want to use that? because views are class instances, so if you add them to another place they will be removed from the previous one.

Comment: .@Naresh so you are saying I cannot reuse uisegmentcontrol..? and that even if I try what you suggested, then it will only show a segmentcontrol in one view and not a second one in some other place with different options...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,
Note the order you send the options will be used when adding titles.

```
func getSegmentControl(with options: [HomeOptions]) -> UISegmentedControl{
    let segmentControl = UISegmentedControl.init()
    for i in 0..<options.count {
        segmentControl.setTitle(option.title, forSegmentAt: i)
    }
    //do additional operations here
    return segmentControl
}
```

Suggestion - Change the name of your enum from HomeOptions to HomeOption.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UISegmentControl like this :

```
let segmentControl = UISegmentedControl.init()
for i in 0..<yourOptions.count {
    let option = yourOptions[i]
    segmentControl.setTitle(option.title, forSegmentAt: i)
}
segmentControl.frame = yourDesiredFrame
yourView.addSubView(segmentControl)
```

here yourOptions is the array of Options , yourDesiredFrame is the frame that you want the UISegmentControl to have and yourView is the view in which you want to add this UISegmentControl.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I just did.